# VBA number to time

Tags: excel, vba, date, time

I have times given to me in the below formats

```
0 
30
145
1310
2115
43015
110015
```

I need to format them in the below format

```
00:00:00
00:00:30
00:01:45
00:13:10
00:21:15
04:30:15
11:00:15
```

I am currently doing this by spliting out in a table for HH, MM and SS and then putting together using =TIME(HH:MM:SS)

Can anyone suggest a Macro to do this for Time and also Date which I am getting as 20141122 currently and I am splitting out the same way

Comment: What is wrong with your current approach?

Comment: I am looking to feed this out to a team and I don't want them messing up the tables or cutting and pasting data incorrectly - the over all plan is to intergrate this into a Macro and produce a file for them - leaving this file as a Black box that they don't touch or edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
Public Function TeTime(r As Range) As Date
    t = r.Text
    l = Len(t)
    t2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Rept("0", 6 - l) & t
    TeTime = TimeSerial(Left(t2, 2), Mid(t2, 3, 2), Right(t2, 2))
End Function
```

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In VBA simply:

```
time_string = format$(time_int, "00:00:00")
```